# Electrical outlet

Tags: electrical

I purchased a small freezer and the instructions state to plug it into a three prong outlet. In my garage there is a 2 prong outlet that I use with an adaptor. Is it safe for me to plug the freezer into the 2 prong outlet with an adaptor?

Is it safe if I plugged it into one of those outlet strips?  I would be plugging the strip into the two prong outlet with an adaptor.

Thank you in advance!  E

Answer (score 8):

One way to do this, that is National Electrical Code compliant. Would be to replace the two prong receptacle, with a GFCI receptacle.  While this does not provide an effective fault current path, it should prevent electrocution in the event of a fault.

Technically to be code compliant, you'll have to stick a "No Equipment Ground" sticker on the GFCI receptacle. There should be one in the box that the GFCI receptacle comes in.

Those three prong adapters that connect to the faceplate screw, do not provide an effective fault current path. And therefore would not allow a fault to be cleared by the breaker.

The "correct" way to do this, would be to install a code compliant grounding conductor and three prong receptacle. Though since the receptacle is in a garage, GFCI protection is required anyway.

***NOTES:***

- *Even though most modern devices should work with GFCI devices, some manufacturers still produce equipment that may trip the GFCI.*

Answer (score 2):

Either way you are using your appliance without the grounding conductor required (for safety reasons) by the manufacturer.

Will it work? **Yes**

Is it safe? **Homes were not wired with grounding conductors for many decades**

Should you look into alternative grounding methods for your appliance? **Yes**

The "adapter" you reference is likely equipped with a grounding terminal to facilitate an auxiliary, or supplemental, grounding conductor. You should see if you can run a wire from the terminal to a grounding rod or other suitable appurtenance such as a metal cold water pipe that has an uninterrupted path to the earth.

[image]

Some people attach the adapter to the cover plate with the plate screw, assuming this "grounds" the adapter. This is only the case if the receptacle is bonded to a metal box which is grounded, and that is rarely true in a home with 2-prong receptacles.

[image]

Comment: Running the grounding conductor to *earth*, does not provide an effective fault current path. Without the fault current path, the breaker will not clear the fault. The grounding conductor must provide a low impedance path back to the *source*, not the *earth*.

Comment: Hey, I was just going to warn him that people around here think the Circuit Breaker cares where ground is or it won't trip.

Comment: @Iggy It doesn't care where ground is, it cares about resistance. If your path to ground is high resistance, it can easily have a fault and NOT draw enough current to trip a breaker.

Comment: @Iggy If you have a ground-fault, and no effective fault current path. You'll be crispy bacon before the breaker trips.  Don't believe me, try this: Cut the female end off an extension cord, and expose the hot wire.  Plug in the cord, and carefully take the other end outside.  Now stick the exposed hot wire into the ground.  Does the breaker trip?

Comment: @GrantOh I know & Jimmy had it right. But boy, I tried to explain it here & I got massacred twice. People here, apparently, think a ground has to go through the panel only because if the CB can't see it, then it'll just plain refuse to trip.

Comment: @Tester101 I never said that & Jimmy here didn't say that. We both said to do a proper ground & the CB will do it's thing no problem & that doesn't mean for the whole panel or only from or to the panel. An individual circuit or even outlet will have the same exact perfect CB result.

Comment: @Iggy I was commenting on this statement "*that has an uninterrupted path to the earth.*".  You don't need a path to **earth**, you need a path to the **source**.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. All grounds are a direct path to the earth...this discharge is what registers with the CB in order to trip. Only if the CB were replaced with a non-intelligent Fuse would the ground to earth then be pointless & useless. The CB is what makes the grounding to earth effective.

Comment: @Iggy I think you misunderstand how circuit breakers work, how the grounding system works, and how ground-faults work.

Comment: Then, please explain it. I haven't been in chat yet, so I might need some instruction to get in.

Comment: @Iggy, the earth has NOTHING to do with breakers tripping and clearing faults. The term "ground" is erroneous when it comes to equipment grounding. We call it ground, but it has NOTHING to do with the dirt ground outside. All "grounds" are NOT "direct paths to the earth".  Equipment grounds are direct paths back to THE SOURCE, as Tester101 correctly pointed out.

Comment: Maybe you need a path to the source for the breaker to trip; that's for fire protection. **Any** available current path to *earth* that has less resistance than a human body will provide some fault current protection for the human who happens to get in the way.

Comment: That's why you provide a current path to **earth** for your antenna, no path to the "source" of the lightning that strikes it.

Comment: Interesting conversation and the group has covered just about everything. A low impedance path back to the source is the purpose of the equipment ground. The only small thing I would add is that the earthing or grounding of an electrical system does have something to do with the "dirt". That is how it got its name. The reason for bonding the equipment grounding system together and then grounding it, is to equalize the voltage potential between all the metal parts and piping systems in a building with each other AND that of the earth around it. It isn't for the operation of the OCPD.